# libGL.so missing after NVIDIA driver installation

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

On Ubuntu 14.04 with nouveau display driver I did the following:

1) Installation of NVIDIA kernel driver (display worked correctly)

Now I'd like to undo this installation and return to the nouveau drivers:

2) Uninstallation of NVIDIA kernel driver
3) remove all nouveau blacklist entries in modprobe.d

When I try to log into X as a user the login process throws me immediately back to the username/password prompt.

I see a potential problem in the xsession log:

.xsession-errors:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: hud main process (3506) terminated with status 127
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (3514) terminated with status 1
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: unity-settings-daemon main process (3502) killed by TERM signal
init: logrotate main process (3405) killed by TERM signal
init: unity-panel-service main process (3518) killed by TERM signal
init: xsession-init main process (3499) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
init: window-stack-bridge main process (3436) killed by KILL signal
```

This error did not occur before installation of NVIDIA driver. How can I manually (re-) install this library?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe try this:

```
sudo bash
cd /use/share/xsession
gedit Xsession
```

and enter this in the file:

```
[Default Entry]
Name=Xsession
Exec=/use/share/xsession~
```

And it might work fine this way.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Although I'd prefer not to add a config file to solve a problem that wasn't there before. I'd prefer to reinstall the package that file came from. BTW, the file you ask me to edit is not there it would be a new file. Also, is it /use or /usr ?

Comment: I think I should alert you that the structure you use for answers is _not at all what an answer should look like._ You make it seem like you aren't sure that what you suggest is going to work, and that's really bad to put as  an answer. If you aren't sure that something will work, then put it as a comment. If you really think that it is the solution, __then be affirmative.__ No one's going to want to listen to the guy saying "I think this might work, but I'm not really sure." They want to follow the person who seems like they know what they're doing. Be more assertive when you answer questions

Comment: otherwise it isn't an answer; it's a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I reinstalled (apt-get install --reinstall) all installed packages that start with the name libgl*

That solved it, without any tempering with config files.